# C# linq expression a better to string

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I need to print a linq expression as it is written in the source code. I have searched for solutions, but so far the recommendation is to use expr.ToString().

This won't work for me. For example, if I have an expression:

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> expr = v => v + 1;
```

ToString() would return `v => (v + 1)`

Now if I make a minor modification to the above case

```
var a = 3;
Expression<Func<int, int>> expr = v => v + a;
```

then ToString() returns `v => (v + value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).a)`. I am looking for something like `v => (v + a)`

My current use case is that I have a set of rules declared as `Expression<Func<TSource, ValidationResult>>`, then I need to benchmark how long it took to execute them, and for that I need to label them properly. ToString() on a rule will produce a string that is not very readable; just like the above example anything not defined in the calling class will be prefixed with a long string indicating where the token is from.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to print out a string containing the original source.

Comment: You would need to parse the expressions pody into its atomic parts. What if your expression was `v => v + myMethod()`? There´s no single solution to this, you have to do this yourself.

Comment: As I was reminded in another context, local references are lifted into compiler generated classes in lambda expressions, but I don't see why a `Regex` removal of `value(.+)\.` wouldn't be good enough?

Comment: As mentioned in a comment to @Xiaoy312's answer Regex-based solution has issues, e.g., with calling static methods of another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ReadableExpressions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AgileObjects.ReadableExpressions) to pretty print it:

```
var a = 3;
Expression<Func<int, int>> expr = v => v + a;

expr.ToReadableString(); // "v => v + a"
```

Comment: Nice package.  Documentation:  https://github.com/AgileObjects/ReadableExpressions

Comment: With the package I found something. If one creates an expression in some class and calls an instance method of the class in the expression the method call is displayed as static which is not quite correct. I tryed to remove matches to regular expression @"value\\(.*?\\)\.", but it has its issies too.